# Calling js functions in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I hit a bump in the road when trying to validate an email via regex. I am getting an undefined function error when trying to use the built-in JavaScript .test() method, for regex testing. Are there some sort of special keywords to use when referencing these types of functions?

Thanks! I appreciate your input.

These are the two sections of codes causing problems.

```
class LoginForm extends Component {

state = { email: '', password: '', warning: '', loading: false, color:     '#FFFFFF' };

  onButtonPress() {
      const { email, password } = this.state;

  this.setState({ loading: true });
  this.setState({ warning: '' });

  if (this.verifyEmail(email)) {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
    .catch(() => {
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
        .catch(this.onLoginFail.bind(this));
    });
  }
  else {
    this.onLoginFail.bind(this);
  }
}

  verifyEmail = (email) => {
    const regex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.)?    (gmail)\.com$';
    return regex.test(email);
  }
```

Comment: you appear to be trying to call [`RegExp.prototype.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) on a String object. Try turning your string into an actual RegExp

Comment: Yeap, that makes sense. I haven't messed with js in quite some time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your regex just a String but not a real regex, you should create a regex like this:

```
verifyEmail = (email) => {
    const regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.)?    (gmail)\.com$/;
    return regex.test(email);
}
```

the regex are often reused. so i suggest you do this:

```
const regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.)?    (gmail)\.com$/;

var verifyEmail = (email) => {
    return regex.test(email);
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer rather than just dumping a code snippet.

Comment: that did the trick, for some reason I remembered having to use quotes in the past. Thanks!

Comment: you can create a regex from a string like this: 
var regex = new Regex('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.)?    (gmail)\.com$')